# animate div when dragging

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, drag

I'm trying to animate a div when I'm dragging another div.

I have an image inside a div and when I drag this image I'd like to animate/move some other div with another speed.

So the main question is how can I animate divs while I'm dragging other elements?

Can anyone help me with this?

Regards

Comment: You're using a custom Drag or jQuery UI ?  without seeing any code you should buy us a crystal sphere.

Comment: Well.. I dont have an idea how to get there... what I have is $("#img").draggable({ axis: "x", containment: [-2698, 0, 0, 0], scroll: false  }); wich allows me to drag my image. But what I want is to have some other images or divs moving faster on top of my main image when I drag this...

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI does this very nicely:

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#visual-feedback

Comment: thank you robotsushi.. but I couldn't find the solution on this response. However I'm very appreciated.

Comment: Use the jquery animate method when the drag event is fired +D

Comment: ok I understand that... makes sense to me... But, How to specify the speed? I want that the speed of the animate is proportional with the speed of dragging?

Comment: The first parameter of animate is the speed you want in milliseconds.

Comment: But I think that is a constant value. So if I drag fast or slow the speed is going to be the same! Is it possible to set the speed according with the "drag speed"?

Comment: As you said I used the animate method when the drag event is fired: $("#img").draggable({ axis: "x", containment: [-2698, 0, 0, 0], scroll: false, 
  drag: function() {
    $("#text_pos1").animate({ "left": "-=300" }, 1500);
   } 
  }); but this is moving always at the same speed..